# Compress an ordered sequence of uint32

Tags: algorithm, compression

Given that the array of unique uint32 is an ordered fixed-width'ed sequence and its size can vary from thousand to million, what's the options there to compress it to minimal size?

Comment: If you know how many numbers there are, you can use Golomb encoding, which is optimal if the numbers are random (but sorted). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664432/compression-algorithm-for-sorted-integers/12664901#12664901

Answer (score 2):

Start by replacing it with an note of the first value and an array of differences between successive values. The easiest thing to do would be to run some general purpose compression algorithm like zip on the array of differences. If you wanted to do something from scratch you might try encoding the differences as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_omega_coding and then using a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding on the result, treated as a byte stream or perhaps stream of 16-bit values.

Comment: btw, this thread is also impressive for this question, for someone may also need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers?rq=1