# Compactly serializing 64 bit integers

Tags: java, arrays, networking, compression

What are some of the techniques that can be used to a efficiently send a large list of integers over the wire ?

I have 100k - 1M (sorted) integers that I need to serialize and send it over the network.

A simple technique that I can think of is to encode each of them in base36 which reduces the size.

Comment: Why encode them at all (as base36) instead of just sending 64 bit for each value (which is smaller than base36-encoded)? Btw, does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664432/compression-algorithm-for-sorted-integers ?

Comment: Please check this other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers there's a reference to a Java library

Comment: Base36 is going to _increase_ the size.  The only way you're going to improve on the basic approach of sending 64 bits is if you know some properties about the numbers: are they small?  Are they repetitive?

Comment: The response format is json so each number would be end up taking a byte, I can try an alternate serialization format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is that big, you can apply a zip over the serialized numbers to reduce the size. Base36 indeed may reduce the size.

Further optimizations require some information and assumptions over the numbers.

E.g., as the numbers are sorted, you can send the first "full" number, and for the rest, difference between the number and the previous "full".

Going beyond, if you can guarantee that the difference between 2 neighbors is less than a 32-bits number (Integer.MAX_VALUE), you can place 2 numbers on a 64 bit space: `delta1 + (delta2 << 64)`.

But as mentioned, all other optimizations rely on information about the numbers.