# Compression for incremental non-repeating integers

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a sequence of unique integers, for example: {2,4,7,9,31,46,...}, which I want to compress. The compression refers to reducing the number of integers in the sequence, and the integers in this sequence are monotonically increasing.

I have found a compression technique based on Horner's algorithm that converts n integers into one integer, but I couldn't find any other better compression technique for a sequence of incremental non-repeating integers. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to get an idea so that I could start with.

Comment: Rice/Golomb encoding. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12664901/1566221

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compression algorithm for sorted integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664432/compression-algorithm-for-sorted-integers)

Comment: @rici  Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not sure Golom coding is applicable to our scenario, since here our goal is to reduce the number of integers, not the space.

Comment: @LiorKogan Thanks for your reply, this answer is to reduce the space size of sorted integers, however, my goal is to reduce the number of integers in the sequence, which may not be completely positively related to space.

Answer (score 0):

You would start by taking the differences: 2, 2, 3, 2, 22, 15, ... Then the ability to compress would depend on the distribution of those differences. A quick thing to try would be encoding the differences as variable-length integers, and then applying an existing lossless compressor, such as lzma2 (xz).